# How can I save myself from Arcbond?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I run a white and red burn deck with an [Arcbond](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcbond) and want to be able to save myself from taking damage but still have it deal the damage to everyone else.

Are there any white or red cards that could do this?

Comment: In what format?

Comment: Is there an enchantment version of this card? I would quite like to cast it on an indestructible creature and cause chaos with it...

Answer (score 7):

Choose a card from your format, undefined, to give the targeted creature lifelink.

Comment: Genius. Or just run creatures *with* lifelink.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of common types of damage mitigation cards in those colors (primarily white): damage replacement effects and damage prevention effects. A [search for damage replacement effects in those colors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%7C%5BW%5D%7C%5BR%5D&text=%20%5Bm/If%5Csa%5Cssource%5Cswould%5Csdeal%5Csdamage%5Csto%5Csyou/%5D) finds 3 cards:

- [Ajani Steadfast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ajani%20Steadfast)'s ultimate ability says

  > −7: You get an emblem with "If a source would deal damage to you or a planeswalker you control, prevent all but 1 of that damage."
- [Gisela, Blade of Goldnight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gisela%2C%20Blade%20of%20Goldnight) has the ability

  > If a source would deal damage to you or a permanent you control, prevent half that damage, rounded up.
- [Hedron-Field Purists](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hedron-Field%20Purists) can level up to gain the abilities

  > If a source would deal damage to you or a creature you control, prevent 1 of that damage.

  and

  > If a source would deal damage to you or a creature you control, prevent 2 of that damage.

A different [search for damage prevention effects in those colors](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+@(%7C%5BW%5D%7C%5BR%5D)&text=+%5Bm/Prevent(%5Cs%5Cw+)*%5Csdamage%5Csthat%5Cswould%5Csbe%5Csdealt%5Csto%5Cs(you%7Ctarget%5Csplayer)/%5D) yields another 18 cards.

Answer (score 2):

Cards that I would suggest are [Purity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140214), [Personal Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220235) (when doing it on your turn) or maybe [Runed Halo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=154005) (naming the card you are going to cast Arcbond on)